# Error: protect(): protection stack overflow while writing file with dbWriteTable (RSQLite)

Tags: r, database, out-of-memory, filesize, rsqlite

I attempt to write a data.frame with 285,476 rows and 17 columns into the SQlite database using dbWriteTable from RSQLite package. I get a following error:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /    options(expressions=)?
```

I have then increased the limit

```
options(expressions = 500000)
```

and tried again, only to receive similar error:

```
Error: protect(): protection stack overflow
```

The writing to text file is without an issue and creates a file of ~50MB.

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: File a bug with reproducible code

Answer (score 1):

While preparing the bug report, I have found out that the above issue is caused by loading 'rworldmap' package (1.3-6) along with the 'RSQlite' package (1.0.0) in R 3.3.0 (while running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1; x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)). The SQLite upload works as long as 'rworldmap' is not loaded or in previous R versions (3.1.1; rworldmap 1.3-6; RSQLite 0.11.4).

See below:

## R 3.3.0 RSQLite bug/conflict with rworldmap

```
require(RSQLite) # load package
require(rworldmap)

# created dataframe
    my.df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:500000,
                col2 = as.character("blah"),
                col3 = as.character("blahblahblah"),
                col4 = as.character("2016-08-10 12:47:07"), 
                col5 = as.character("2016-08-10 12:47:07"), 
                col6 = as.character("2016-08-10 12:47:07"), 
                col7 = as.character("2016-08-10 12:47:07"), 
                col8 = as.character("2016-08-10 12:47:07"), 
                col9 = as.character("2016-08-10 12:47:07"), 
                col10 = as.character("2016-08-10 12:47:07"), 
                col11 = as.character("2016-08-10 12:47:07"), 
                col12 = 1,col13 = 1,col14 = 1,col15 = 1,col16 = 1,col17 = 1,col18 = 1
                )

# connect and upload to SQLite database 
        db=paste("test.sqlite",sep="")

        conLite = dbConnect(dbDriver("SQLite"),dbname = db)
        dbGetQuery(conLite,paste( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test"))
        dbWriteTable(conn=conLite, name = 'test', value = my.df, row.names = FALSE) 
        # R 3.3.0 gives: Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
        dbDisconnect(conLite)
```

### sessionInfo()   for R version 3.3.0

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rworldmap_1.3-6 sp_1.2-3        RSQLite_1.0.0   DBI_0.4-1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] foreign_0.8-66  fields_8.4-1    maps_3.1.0      maptools_0.8-39
[5] grid_3.3.0      spam_1.3-0      lattice_0.20-33
```

## sessionInfo() for R version 3.1.1

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rworldmap_1.3-6 sp_1.0-15       RSQLite_0.11.4  DBI_0.3.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] fields_8.3-6    foreign_0.8-61  grid_3.1.1      lattice_0.20-29
[5] maps_2.3-9      maptools_0.8-30 spam_1.3-0
```